# Редирект с querystring Vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Мне от Гугла (при авторизации) приходит querystring. Однако Vue-router , делает редирект на языковую зону без нее.  Как сделать редирект с сохранением querystring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала надо сохранить `query`:

```
const { query } = this.$route
this.$router.push({
  path: '/path/to/redirect',
  query
})
```